# Is there a Guest Session under Ubuntu Gnome 15.04?

Tags: gnome, 15.04, guest-session

As I don't really like the guest session very much I don't really want it, but I was just wondering if it actually exists under Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 (as that is what I am running), or if it can be activated as there does not seem to be one as default?

Comment: [Here](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2015/04/28/disable-guest-session-ubuntu-15-04/) is a topic about Disable Guest Session in Ubuntu 15.04 Login Screen, so i think it's exist :)

Comment: @Serphiroth: It is different in Gnome Shell though as it does not come enabled by default, if it exists at all.

Comment: @Serphiroth: So how would I enable it in Gnome Shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GDM instead of LightDM installed, then there is no guest session. The configuration of the guest session is part of the `lightdm` package.

Therefore you could install `lightdm` to get the guest session back **>:)**

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

<sub>`apt` – yes, in Ubuntu 15.04 you can use this command</sub>